# In .vimrc, function when cursor between brackets/braces and enter is pressed

Tags: vim

The question kind of describes what I'm trying to do.  Right now I'm using

`inoremap { {}<Left>`

To place the cursor between the brackets.  The next thing I'm trying to achieve is if the cursor is between and enter is pressed, the result should be:

`{
    | <-cursor
}`

Seems like maybe it should be simple but after some Googling, I couldn't find a solution. (still very novice at vim scripts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have in [lh-brackets](https://github.com/luchermitte/lh-brackets) could be summarized as

```
inoremap <expr> <cr> getline(".")[col(".")-2:col(".")-1]=="{}" ? "<cr><esc>O" : "<cr>"
```

(But it's actually a little bit more complex as other conditions could be added)

Comment: Beautiful and does exactly when I needed...AND does not interfere with omni-complete!

Answer (score 3):

Hate to answer my own question but finally figured it out:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "\<CR>" : "\<Esc>:call Checkcursor()\<CR>"
function! Checkcursor()
  let b:letters = strcharpart(getline('.')[col('.') - 1:], 0, 2)
  if b:letters == '{}'
    call feedkeys("li\<CR>\<Esc>\ko", "n")
  else
    call feedkeys('o')
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

You can record a macro...

```
qai{<cr><cr>}<esc>ki<tab><esc>q

@a
```

To leave the macro in insert mode you can append to the macro

```
ii<esc>y"A$
```

You also might want to try something like [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not very familiar with macros and recording them so I'm trying to stick with .vimrc file.  Right now I'm using `inoremap <Leader><Space> <CR><Esc>ko` to trigger the desired result whenever I need it.

Comment: Another way to do this is using a normal map: `nnoremap <leader>{ i{<cr><cr>}<esc>ki<tab>`.  Ultisnips is your best bet though.